# Boot tiny core linux in uefi mode

Tags: boot, uefi, coreos

I was trying to tweak Core linux to boot in uefi mode, but it's only working in legacy mode and i don't really know how to start with it, i tried copying efi from ubuntu server install but i just booted to uefi shell.
Tree looks like this

```
Core
├───boot
│   │   core.gz
│   │   vmlinuz
│   │
│   └───grub
│       │   efi.img
│       │   font.pf2
│       │   grub.cfg
│       │   loopback.cfg
│       │
│       └───x86_64-efi
│               acpi.mod
│               adler32.mod
│               ahci.mod
│               all_video.mod
│               aout.mod
│               appleldr.mod
│               archelp.mod
│               ata.mod
│               at_keyboard.mod
│               backtrace.mod
│               bfs.mod
│               bitmap.mod
│               bitmap_scale.mod
│               blocklist.mod
│               boot.mod
│               bsd.mod
│               bswap_test.mod
│               btrfs.mod
│               bufio.mod
│               cat.mod
│               cbfs.mod
│               cbls.mod
│               cbmemc.mod
│               cbtable.mod
│               cbtime.mod
│               chain.mod
│               cmdline_cat_test.mod
│               cmp.mod
│               cmp_test.mod
│               command.lst
│               cpio.mod
│               cpio_be.mod
│               cpuid.mod
│               crc64.mod
│               crypto.lst
│               crypto.mod
│               cryptodisk.mod
│               cs5536.mod
│               ctz_test.mod
│               date.mod
│               datehook.mod
│               datetime.mod
│               disk.mod
│               diskfilter.mod
│               div.mod
│               div_test.mod
│               dm_nv.mod
│               echo.mod
│               efifwsetup.mod
│               efinet.mod
│               efi_gop.mod
│               efi_uga.mod
│               ehci.mod
│               elf.mod
│               eval.mod
│               exfat.mod
│               exfctest.mod
│               ext2.mod
│               f2fs.mod
│               fat.mod
│               fdt.lst
│               file.mod
│               fixvideo.mod
│               font.mod
│               fs.lst
│               gcry_arcfour.mod
│               gcry_blowfish.mod
│               gcry_camellia.mod
│               gcry_cast5.mod
│               gcry_crc.mod
│               gcry_des.mod
│               gcry_dsa.mod
│               gcry_idea.mod
│               gcry_md4.mod
│               gcry_md5.mod
│               gcry_rfc2268.mod
│               gcry_rijndael.mod
│               gcry_rmd160.mod
│               gcry_rsa.mod
│               gcry_seed.mod
│               gcry_serpent.mod
│               gcry_sha1.mod
│               gcry_sha256.mod
│               gcry_sha512.mod
│               gcry_tiger.mod
│               gcry_twofish.mod
│               gcry_whirlpool.mod
│               geli.mod
│               gettext.mod
│               gfxmenu.mod
│               gfxterm.mod
│               gfxterm_background.mod
│               gfxterm_menu.mod
│               gptsync.mod
│               grub.cfg
│               gzio.mod
│               halt.mod
│               hashsum.mod
│               hdparm.mod
│               help.mod
│               hexdump.mod
│               hfs.mod
│               hfsplus.mod
│               hfspluscomp.mod
│               http.mod
│               iorw.mod
│               jfs.mod
│               jpeg.mod
│               keylayouts.mod
│               keystatus.mod
│               ldm.mod
│               legacycfg.mod
│               legacy_password_test.mod
│               linux.mod
│               linux16.mod
│               linuxefi.mod
│               loadbios.mod
│               loadenv.mod
│               loopback.mod
│               ls.mod
│               lsacpi.mod
│               lsefi.mod
│               lsefimmap.mod
│               lsefisystab.mod
│               lsmmap.mod
│               lspci.mod
│               lssal.mod
│               luks.mod
│               lvm.mod
│               lzopio.mod
│               macbless.mod
│               macho.mod
│               mdraid09.mod
│               mdraid09_be.mod
│               mdraid1x.mod
│               memrw.mod
│               minicmd.mod
│               minix2.mod
│               minix2_be.mod
│               minix3.mod
│               minix3_be.mod
│               minix_be.mod
│               mmap.mod
│               moddep.lst
│               morse.mod
│               mpi.mod
│               msdospart.mod
│               multiboot.mod
│               multiboot2.mod
│               mul_test.mod
│               nativedisk.mod
│               net.mod
│               newc.mod
│               ntfs.mod
│               ntfscomp.mod
│               odc.mod
│               offsetio.mod
│               ohci.mod
│               partmap.lst
│               parttool.lst
│               parttool.mod
│               part_acorn.mod
│               part_amiga.mod
│               part_apple.mod
│               part_bsd.mod
│               part_dfly.mod
│               part_dvh.mod
│               part_gpt.mod
│               part_msdos.mod
│               part_plan.mod
│               part_sun.mod
│               part_sunpc.mod
│               password.mod
│               password_pbkdf2.mod
│               pata.mod
│               pbkdf2.mod
│               pbkdf2_test.mod
│               pcidump.mod
│               pgp.mod
│               play.mod
│               png.mod
│               priority_queue.mod
│               probe.mod
│               procfs.mod
│               progress.mod
│               raid5rec.mod
│               raid6rec.mod
│               random.mod
│               rdmsr.mod
│               read.mod
│               reboot.mod
│               regexp.mod
│               reiserfs.mod
│               relocator.mod
│               romfs.mod
│               scsi.mod
│               serial.mod
│               setjmp.mod
│               setjmp_test.mod
│               setpci.mod
│               shift_test.mod
│               shim_lock.mod
│               signature_test.mod
│               sleep.mod
│               sleep_test.mod
│               smbios.mod
│               spkmodem.mod
│               squash4.mod
│               strtoull_test.mod
│               syslinuxcfg.mod
│               terminal.lst
│               terminal.mod
│               terminfo.mod
│               test.mod
│               testload.mod
│               testspeed.mod
│               test_blockarg.mod
│               tftp.mod
│               tga.mod
│               time.mod
│               tpm.mod
│               tr.mod
│               trig.mod
│               true.mod
│               udf.mod
│               ufs1.mod
│               ufs1_be.mod
│               ufs2.mod
│               uhci.mod
│               usb.mod
│               usbms.mod
│               usbserial_common.mod
│               usbserial_ftdi.mod
│               usbserial_pl2303.mod
│               usbserial_usbdebug.mod
│               usbtest.mod
│               usb_keyboard.mod
│               verifiers.mod
│               video.lst
│               video.mod
│               videoinfo.mod
│               videotest.mod
│               videotest_checksum.mod
│               video_bochs.mod
│               video_cirrus.mod
│               video_colors.mod
│               video_fb.mod
│               wrmsr.mod
│               xfs.mod
│               xnu.mod
│               xnu_uuid.mod
│               xnu_uuid_test.mod
│               xzio.mod
│               zfscrypt.mod
│               zstd.mod
│
├───EFI
│   └───BOOT
│           BOOTx64.EFI
│           grubx64.efi
│           mmx64.efi
│
└───isolinux
        boot.cat
        boot.msg
        f2
        f3
        f4
        isolinux.bin
        isolinux.cfg
```

Comment: please, do not assume that everyone would ask the same question ... what is your question?

Comment: How to enable uefi boot

Answer (score 0):

You are booting the 32-bit (x86) version, which won't work with UEFI.

Instead, download the [64-bit (x64) version of TinyCore](http://tinycorelinux.net/14.x/x86_64/release/CorePure64-14.0.iso) and it will work from UEFI.